# regex, how to split names with optional quotes and email addresses in PHP

Tags: php, regex

I have following string:

> **"Johnny Test"** <johnny@test.com>,**Jack** <another@test.com>,**"Scott
>   Summers"** <scotts@test.com> ...

The multi word names are enclosed in double quotes

I need an array with containing the following result:

```
array(   
   array('nom' => 'Johnny Test', 'adresse' => 'johnny@test.com'),
   array('nom' => 'Jack', 'adresse' => 'another@test.com'),     
   array('nom' => 'Scott Summers', 'adresse' => 'scotts@test.com') 
   ... 
   )
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
preg_match_all('/(.*?)\s<(.*?)>,?/', $string, $hits);
print_r($hits);
```

something like this should work.

If you have `\r\n` inside the string use this before parsing it with the regex:

```
$chars=array("\r\n", "\n", "\r");
$string=str_replace($chars, '', $string);
```

UPDATE: Code I'm using to test this.

test_preg2.php:

```
<?php
$html='"Johnny Test" <johnny@test.com>,Jack <another@test.com>,"Scott Summers" <scotts@test.com>';
$chars=array("\r\n", "\n", "\r");
$html=str_replace($chars, '', $html);
preg_match_all('/(.*?)\s<(.*?)>,?/', $html,$hits);
print_r($hits);
?>
```

Output:

```
Array ( [0] => Array ( [0] => "Johnny Test" , [1] => Jack , [2] => "Scott Summers" ) [1] => Array ( [0] => "Johnny Test" [1] => Jack [2] => "Scott Summers" ) [2] => Array ( [0] => johnny@test.com [1] => another@test.com [2] => scotts@test.com ) )
```

UPDATE 2: the string has been formated with htmlentities(). (the sample string of the question is wrong man...)

```
preg_match_all('/(.*?)\s&lt;(.*?)&gt;,?/', $string, $hits);
print_r($hits);
```

Comment: you sure? I just tried it and it does work, the only thing left to do is `$name=str_replace('"', '', $name);` to remove the quotes

Comment: this doesn't work. preg_match_all is returning blank hits:
Array ( [0] => Array ( ) [1] => Array ( ) [2] => Array ( ) )

Comment: I retrieve the data from a form as POST, I have to htmlentities and stripslashes before testing with regex.  I get blank matches

Comment: then your input was wrong, if you have htmlentities you don't have `<` or `>`, you have `&lt;` and `&gt;`

Answer (score 0):

```
$all  = array();
$data = '"Johnny Test" <johnny@test.com>,Jack <another@test.com>,"Scott Summers" <scotts@test.com>';
$emails = explode(',', $data);
foreach ($emails as $email)
{
    if (preg_match('/(.*) <(.*)>/', $email, $regs)) {
        $all[] = array(
            'nom'     => trim($regs[1], '"'), 
            'adresse' => $regs[2],
        );
    }
}

print_r($all);
```